# socket class error in python

Tags: python, class, sockets

I'm very new to programing and I've just started trying to open socket so don't be hard on me. 
I'm trying to make a class for my socket functions but when I run the client function it just wont work if I have the "self.sock.connect((host, port))" inside the client function. So I made another function and then just called it from the client function. But the problem still remains for the host function. I keep getting this error message (down). What am I doing wrong? When should you use self ? (PS: I've done this before without making it to a class, then it worked.)

```
>>> SC.host()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "SocketClass.py", line 30, in host
    self.sock.listen(1)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

the code:

```
 import socket

    class SocketConnect():

        def __init__(self):
            self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

        #def socketSetup(self, host, port):
            #self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            #self.sock.connect((host, port))

        def client(self, host, port):
            self.sock.connect((host, port))
            while True:
                x = raw_input("Vilken fil ska skickas? ")
                try:
                    fo = open(x, "rb")
                    data_to_send = fo.read()
                    self.sock.sendall(data_to_send)
                except:
                    print "***Filen kunde inte hittas***"

                self.sock.sendall(data_to_send)

            data = self.sock.recv(1024)
            self.sock.close()

        def host(self):
            self.sock.listen(1)
            conn, addr = self.sock.accept()

            print "Connected by: " + str(addr)

            while True:
                data = conn.recv(1024)
                file = open("pic.png", "wb")
                file.write(data)

            conn.close()
```

Comment: You need to bind the socket first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to listen then you should specify to listen on what?

```
def host(self):
    self.sock.bind(('0.0.0.0', 1234))
    self.sock.listen(1)
    ...
```

Now the host will listen at port 1234 and accept connections from any ip.